# How to call regular method in dll from Unity script?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Let's say I have a very simple native dll with name `MyNativeDll` that contains such a method:

```
extern "C" {
    int foo() { return 777; }
}
```

I built this `MyNativeDll.dll` and put it under Assets dir.

Now, I need to call this method from Unity. What I do is :

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const string pluginName = "MyNativeDll";
    //native interface
    [DllImport(pluginName)]
    private static extern int foo();

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int i = foo();
        Debug.Log($"HERE :: {i}");
    }
}
```

If I run my Unity project I get such an errors

```
EntryPointNotFoundException: foo
TestScript.Update () (at Assets/TestScript.cs:20)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the path to the DLL correct? See e.g. here https://answers.unity.com/questions/1360004/entrypointnotfoundexception-native-plugin-help.html

Comment: @derHugo I am not sure what exactly do you mean "path to DLL"?